# Using str_replace on array

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I've got a problem which I can't seem to find a solution to. In a foreach loop

```
foreach( $results->result as $item )
```

the following code

```
$item->title = str_replace( " - Home", "", $item->title );
```

always throws an error

> **Catchable fatal error**: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I thought `str_replace` was able to handle arrays? What would I need to change in order to get this working?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It can handle arrays, but in your case `$item->title` is an object.

Comment: Thank you all for your amazingly quick help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an array, it's an object, *as the error says*... did you get it with `json_decode()` by any chance?

However, the solution is simple - cast it to an array:

```
$item->title = str_replace( " - Home", "", (array) $item->title );
```

Another point about this is that if you are wanting to modify the data held in `$results->result`, and not just a copy of it, you will need your `foreach` to be:

```
foreach( $results->result as &$item )
```

...and get item as a reference, not a copy...

Answer (score 2):

Do a `var_dump` on `$item->title`, because it isn't an array, it is an object. `str_replace` can only handle actual arrays and strings. If you're expecting this to be an array, then you might have some problems elsewhere and I would look into that.

If you're just looking for a patch, you might be able to get away with casting it. If everything else is working, I would do this because it really has the fewest side-effects:

```php
// convert it to an array before passing it through str_replace
// (array) $item->title
// then convert it back to its original form by casting the result back
// (object) str_replace
$item->title = (object) str_replace( " - Home", "", (array) $item->title );
```

If `title` has to be an array, you can get away without the `(object)`, but I think it would be a better idea to track down where `title` is being set and have the value correct to begin with.

---

BTW — if you're planning on using `$item->title` outside of the loop, you also need to make sure you are using a reference so that the item itself is updated:

```
foreach($results->result as &$item)
{
     $item->title = (object) str_replace( " - Home", "", (array) $item->title );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$item->title` seems to be an object of type `stdClass`, and not a string. Do `var_dump($item->title)` to see what the object looks like.

Also, you loop won't do what you expect, after the loop has finished, all objects in `$results->result` will still have the same values (use `foreach($results->result as &$item)` (pass by reference))